# Chrome extension - app with icon in toolbar

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

So I have made extension app which you can launch only from new tab -> apps page.

Most of people can start my extension normally but some use Speed dial extension that overrides this page. For them I wanted to put icon for starting the app on toolbar.

But somehow I haven't found any way to do this except with "browser_action" or "page_action".

Is this really not possible?

**UPDATE:**

Ok, so this can't be made. But is there any workaround for users using Speed dial extension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you can't

see doc from https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest.html

you can choose only one type at a time

```
      // Pick one (or none)
      "browser_action": {...},
      "page_action": {...},
      "theme": {...},
      "app": {...},
```

this doc helps you to choose

https://developers.google.com/chrome/web-store/docs/choosing